# Getting unhandled exception in using Graphics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I get  **unhandled exception** when I run this code:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
 {
   g.DrawImage(imageInput, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
               rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
 }
```

It says :

> System.ArgumentNullException : 'The value can not be null. Parameter
>   name: image

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the target here? not possible to decide based on the code you've posted , Can you post related code and the full exception please

Comment: Thank you for your help I changed the code. I used ROI to extract the part I want from the image. If you want me to send the old one I ll !!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `imageInput` is `null`. `Parameter name: image` is the important part. If you take a look at the documentation for [DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see it takes an `image` parameter. This is the first argument passed to `DrawImage`, which corresponds with `imageInput`.

Therefore, you need to initialise `imageInput`.

Comment: I already did :   `imageInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
                 imageBox1.Image = imageInput;`

Comment: @Chaima Soltani  And what Image format is `imageInput`? Does that constructor (`new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);`) produce a valid .NET Image, since it's not a standard one? `Image` here is not a .NET `System.Drawing.Image` (abstract) class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a source image; `imageInput` can't be null.

Comment: Already done : `imageInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName); imageBox1.Image = imageInput; `